# jQuery uploader that supports Directories

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload

Is there any jQuery file uploader that supports selecting Directories and can upload all content within those folders to the server? We need a solution that we can implement in our asp.net MVC project.

The only viable that we probably can use - is a building a Silverlight app, but maybe there is better approach?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot see the local filesystem for security reasons, therefore it cannot send folders or multiple file selections. jQuery, being JavaScript, cannot get past this limitation.

Alternatives: use Flash, Java or Active-X

Comment: uploadify jQuery plugin uses Flash uploader, but on the higher level it is still a jQuery plugin, so you can do ajax style stuff. But I'm not sure if it possible to tweak it to select directories

Comment: other tool that built as a jQuery plugin: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload